# Custom rule for jquery Validation plugin (regex)

Tags: jquery, regex

Can you help me write two rules that check phoneNumber?
First rule: start with +7 or 8 then any ten numbers.
Examples:

```
+77017223457 - valid
77017223457 -not valid
87017223457 - valid
```

Second rule: start with +7 or 8 then three numbers from set:
 {700, 701, 702, 705, 707, 712, 713, 717, 718,721, 725, 726, 727, 777  } then any seven numbers.

Examples:

```
+77074446255 - valid
+77034446255 - not valid (no 703 in the set)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var phone = $("#phoneNumber").val()
var regex = /^((\+7)|8)(700|701|702|705|707|712|713|717|718,721|725|726|727|777)[0-9]{7}$/;
if(regex.test(phone))
   // Phone is valid
else
   // Phone is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:\+7|8)(?:70[0-2]|705|707|71[23]|71[78]|721|72[5-7]|777)[0-9]+
```

or, less compressed but more obvious:

```
(?:\+7|8)(?:700|701|702|705|707|712|713|717|718|721|725|726|727|777)[0-9]+
```

To make sure that this is not a partial match, use `^` and `$`

```
^(?:\+7|8)(?:700|etc|etc)[0-9]+$
```

Comment: you regexp match on '+7701722345'. But, there is nine numbers after +7 (must be 10)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more compact:

```
/^(?/\+7|8)7(?:0[01257]|1[2378]|2[1567]|77)\d{7}$/
```